# How to prevent the keyEquivalent from showing in an NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem

So I've set up an NSPopUpButton menu and populated it with the menu items and set all the key equivalents to what I want.  The problem I'm having is that it automatically displays the key equivalent in the menu items next to the title of the item and I don't want it to.  Is there any way to prevent it?  I've searched the documentation and Google but can't seem to find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

the two ways that would come to mind would be to subclass NSMenuItemCell and do the following:
(untested, but seems like it should work)

```
- (NSRect)keyEquivalentRectForBounds:(NSRect)cellFrame
{
    return NSZeroRect;
}

- (CGFloat)keyEquivalentWidth
{
    return 0.0f;
}
```

or number 2 to remove the key equivalents and handle the events manually.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.  How do I make the program call these methods when I add a menu item or set its keyEquivalent, instead of the existing ones in the NSMenuItemCell class?